# Android MapView getcoordinates by clicking into map

Tags: java, android, android-mapview

How can get the coordinates, if a user is clicking into the Map by MapViewer?
I need two coordinate a start and destination for my routing app. Therefore the user has to click into the map and the app should return the coordinates and set a point on the location. The same should be done for the second click. Afterwards both clicks should be processed by the routing algorithm. I couldn't find any how to or something else which would be related to API17.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429877/how-to-get-screen-coordinates-from-marker-in-google-maps-v2-android. check this might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these links:-

[How do I get the coordinates of a map on tap with MapFragment (not MapView)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362281/how-do-i-get-the-coordinates-of-a-map-on-tap-with-mapfragment-not-mapview)

OR

[Getting coordinates when clicking anywhere on a MapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787204/getting-coordinates-when-clicking-anywhere-on-a-mapview)

OR

[Get the center coordinates of map in Android Mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043688/get-the-center-coordinates-of-map-in-android-mapview)

This may help you..........